# How to handle database synchronization between multiple EBS in different data-centers?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I've been reading documentation on AWS for the past week. There is a lot of information, and it seems there are more than one (correct) way of doing things.

As of right now, we are opting in setting up two EC2 instances each with it's own EBS instance for our database in different datacenters.

Ideally, one EC2 instance in North America, and the other EC2 instance in Europe.

Does Amazon have an automatic EBS synchronization for databases (MySQL and MongoDB) between EBS's? If so how would I go about setting it up?

If it doesn't have an automatic synchronization system, would opting for RDS be more interesting than setting EBS database synchronisation up manually? (Taking in account pricing as well).

Comment: You are using "EBS" in a strange way... "EBS instances" is not a term.  EBS (Elastic Block Store) *volumes* are presented as raw hard drives -- block devices.  There is no mechanism for synchronizing them, because if there were, it would not be useful.  Block devices are under the control of a single machine.  The data can't change out from under the instance to which it is attached.

Answer (score 3):

Syncing EBS can be done with something like [GlusterFS](https://www.gluster.org/), but databases are a bit more complex things, and just syncing filesystem wont work.

For mysql family there are number of replication options depending on version and flavour of the db, e.g. master-master replication, group replication, galera cluster etc.

For mongodb you are limited to [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read on GlusterFS but didn't think it would work with databases. What you're saying is that I handle db synchronisation manually? I also happened to read about this (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.ReplicationInstance.html) what do you think?

Comment: 'manually' is not quite the word. I'd say use native db replication tools. Talking about dms, I never used it. It looks okay for master-slave replication. If you are going to use it, check it carefully. For mysql - how it handles failover, especially how it rolls back transactions. For mongo - how failover affect clients. Client drivers are quite sophisticated managing connection pools. Frankly, I don't see much benefits comparing to native battle-tested replication on the db level.